# How can I bind to the count of the items source in XAML using a style and a DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can bind to the Item source if I call the list by name but, I have not been able to get the binding to work generically by getting the Count of the Items on each individual combobox.

Here is what I would like to do in XAML. What do I need to change for this binding to work?

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="ComboBox">                             
     <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
       </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

   <ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"               
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
      </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) component in your binding:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
             Value="0"
             >
```

The way you currently have it the binding subsystem will look for the `Items.Count` property on whatever you have set as the DataContext of the ComboBox.